# Shell: Robust way to remove trailing decimal point and zero in case there is a zero

Tags: bash, shell, trim, tr

In a bash script I have a (two digit) number with decimal point and one digit following.

In case there's a zero after the decimal separator, I want to trim the separator and the zero.

For

```
foo=26.5
```

..there should be no trimming. But in this case:

```
foo=26.0
```

My desired output would be:

```
foo=26
```

Is `tr` the right choice for it?

I tried it with the `--delete .0` option but it simply deletes all of both character's appearences.

Thank you!

Comment: With bash: `echo "${foo//.0/}"`?

Comment: @Cyrus `8.04` ends up being `84`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only for `bash`:

```
foo=$(echo "$foo" | sed 's/\.0$//')
```

Comment: why not simply foo="${foo%.*}"

Comment: @ctac_: This probably only works for `bash` and removes everything after the dot. I suggest to replace `*` with `0`.

Comment: I think it's ok with all POSIX shell. It seems to me the OP don't tell all. Starting from 26.5, he want to get 26 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
atomic_mass=$(echo $atomic_mass | sed -E 's/(^[0-9]+\.0*[1-9]+)0*$/\1/')
```

for removing zeros at the end of the number after the decimal place.

Example: if `$atomic_mass=26.00250000`, then the output would be `26.0025`.
The code uses capture groups and sed, which is a stream editor in bash with the `-E` or `-r` flag in order to make regular expression matching possible.